# service vboxdrv setup throwing error when installing VirtualBox on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, terminal, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am trying to install VirtualBox 5.0 on a minimal (terminal only) CentOS 7 server, but I keep getting the following error when I type `service vboxdrv setup`:

```
The service command supports only basic LSB actions (start, stop,  
restart, try-restart, reload, force-reload, status). For other  
actions, please try to use systemctl.
```

---

**STEPS LEADING UP TO THE ERROR:**

---

The complete set of steps leading up to the error is as follows:

```
vi /etc/yum.repos.d/virtualbox.repo
```

Add the following text, then save and exit:

```
[virtualbox]
name=Oracle Linux / RHEL / CentOS-$releasever / $basearch – VirtualBox
baseurl=http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/rpm/el/$releasever/$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox.asc
```

Then at command prompt type:

```
# rpm -Uvh http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/Linux/Fedora/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm
# yum install gcc make patch  dkms qt libgomp 
# yum install kernel-headers kernel-devel fontforge binutils glibc-headers glibc-devel
...
Complete!  
# cd /usr/src/kernels
# ls –al
total 12
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root 4096 Sep 25 16:14 .
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root 4096 Sep 25 14:17 ..
drwxr-xr-x. 22 root root 4096 Sep 25 16:14 3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64
# export KERN_DIR=/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64
# yum install VirtualBox-5.0
...
Complete!  
#  yum install "kernel-devel-uname-r == $(uname -r)"
#  setenforce Permissive
# service vboxdrv setup
The service command supports only basic LSB actions (start, stop,  
restart, try-restart, reload, force-reload, status). For other  
actions, please try to use systemctl.
```

Note that I get the same error when running the command as a non-root user that has been added to the `vboxusers` group.

**How can I resolve this error?**

As per @MarkPlotnick's suggestion, I tried the following, but got a different error:

```
[root@localhost kernels]# /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
-bash: /etc/init.d/vboxdrv: No such file or directory
[root@localhost kernels]# -I /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
-bash: -I: command not found
[root@localhost kernels]# cd /etc/init.d
[root@localhost init.d]# ls -al
total 40
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root  4096 Oct  2 12:32 .
drwxr-xr-x. 10 root root  4096 Oct  2 12:32 ..
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 13430 Jan 15  2015 functions
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root  2989 Jan 15  2015 netconsole
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root  6470 Jan 15  2015 network
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  1160 Sep 15 06:21 README
[root@localhost init.d]#
```

Comment: Does `sudo -i /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup` work? That's about all the old `service` command would have done.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick No it does not.  Please see the terminal output from your suggestions, which I just added to the end of my OP.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What do you think `service vboxdrv setup` should do and what made you think that? Complaining about `setup` not being a valid parameter is the behavior that I expect.

Comment: @Gilles  I am trying to install virtualbox in a terminal-only installation of CentOS 7.  These steps worked in my previous attempt a couple days ago.  The steps are my documentation of the result of trial an error using several tutorials which each threw errors, and then my research of each error.  I am trying to document reproduceable steps for installing virtualbox on a minimal, terminal-only, installation of CentOS 7.

Comment: Why aren't you using `yum install virtualbox` (or whatever the package is called on CentOS)? I suspect that you made a mistake when recording your previous attempt, you probably ran some other script with the `setup` argument.

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution:
/usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh setup

This issue seems to come with the most recent VirtualBox-5.0-5.0.6_103037_el7 install/update (this is part of the yum update from 5.0.4 -> 5.0.6:

```
Cleanup    : VirtualBox-5.0-5.0.4_102546_el7-1.x86_64                                                                                       18/18 
warning: file /etc/rc.d/init.d/vboxweb-service: remove failed: No such file or directory

warning: file /etc/rc.d/init.d/vboxdrv: remove failed: No such file or directory

warning: file /etc/rc.d/init.d/vboxballoonctrl-service: remove failed: No such file or directory

warning: file /etc/rc.d/init.d/vboxautostart-service: remove failed: No such file or directory
```

Comment: CentOS 7.6 (`/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64`)
VirtualBox-5.2-5.2.24_128163_el7-1.x86_64
`sudo /usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh setup`
Seems to handle it just fine.